# Change the resolution from bash for Cent OS

Tags: resolution, centos

I changed the resolution of my monitor in KDE but it doesnt fit the screen and it shows an out of range problem is there anyway to reset or change it back from bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xrandr`:

list available modes:

```
xrandr -q
```

select one:

```
xrandr -s n
```

where **n** is the **number of the mode you wish to use**. You can also switch between available modes with the keyboard using:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>

you must use the + and - symbols from the numpad though.

Comment: No guts to explain what the neg was for? These options are **much** easier than editing the x configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit [xorg.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/xorg.conf) to correct the resolution, and then restart X.